# Как выполнить php код из переменной?

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

Здравствуйте.

Пишу свой шаблонизатор.

```
class TemplateAlfa {

    private $templates_dir;
    private $templates_data;
    private $template;

    public function __construct($path){
        $this->templates_dir = $path;
    }

    public function set($name, $value) {
        $this->templates_data[$name] = $value;
        $this->template .= file_get_contents($this->templates_dir.$name.".tpl");
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->templates_data[$name]))
            return $this->templates_data[$name];
        else
            return "";
    }

    public function wrap(){

    }

    public function dysplay() {
        echo $this->template;
    }

    public function render() {
        $str = $this->template;

        eval("$str = "$str";");

        echo $str;

    }
}
```

Есть шаблон .tpl с кодом:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?= $this->header['title']?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

и файл, который вызывает его:

```
$template = new TemplateAlfa($root_dir."template/manager/");

    $header = array(
        "title" => "Групповой редактор",
        "meta" => "",
        "link" => array(
            "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300,700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext",
            "/template/manager/css/style.css",
            "/template/manager/css/modal.css"
        ),

        "scripts" => array(
            "/template/manager/javascript/common.js" => "defer",
            "/template/manager/javascript/dom.js" => ""
        )

    );

    $template->set("header", $header);

    $template->render();
```

Идея такова:

Создаём массив с данными для шаблона.
Вызываем `$template->set("Имя шаблона", $его_данные);`.
Функция set сохраняет данные и читает шаблон, засовывая его в переменную.
Так постепенно формируются полный шаблон (`$template`) и полный массив с данными (`$templates_data`) для разных шаблонов.
А функция `render();` должна выполнять php, который хранится в `$template`, но этого не происходит.

Вопрос: почему и как с этим жить?

Comment: @Станислав Далинин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

[@Станислав Далинин](/users/6975/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD), никогда не пользуйтесь eval'ом. Эта функция нужна в очень узкоспециализрованных случаях, когда нужно симулировать выполнение кода (например, динамическое создание классов, но и тут я сторонник виртуальной файловой системы - при должном автозагрузчике можно прямо из кода отследить происхождение класса). Весь код, который должен выполниться, должен подключаться, как есть. Все остальное должно обрабатываться существующим кодом. Любой шаблонизатор - это программа, которая работает с **токенами** в **текстовом шаблоне**, там есть условная логика, но непосредственно родного кода там нет и не должно быть. Другими словами, шаблон должен выглядеть так:

```
<tag>
    {{ str }}
</tag>
```

А уже шаблонизатор должен разобраться, что `{{ str }}` - это конструкция по выводу контекста str.

Comment: Я бы не стал пользоваться велосипедом, а взял бы там всякие `twig` ... Но в целях самообразования - неплохая вещь свой велосипед

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё такой вариант (не используйте `eval`)

```
ob_start();
include ($this->templates_dir.$name.".tpl");
$str = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

а так?

> > eval("$str = \"$str\";");